# Symfony2: trow on missing translation

Tags: symfony, internationalization

I develop websites based on the Symfony2 framework, and I have quality problems due to missing translations.
This is particular true for non visible translations like image alt attribut or page meta-data.

To solve that problem, I would like Symfony to stop the page render on missing translation, by throwing an exception.

How can I tell the Symfony translator not to accept any missing translation in the dev environment? (for translations made from code, using the translator service and from templates, using the trans filter)

Comment: Why would you do this, the symfony developer toolbar informs you about missing translations!

Comment: @Nickolaus I don't have that. I'm using Symfony 2.6.11, with stock log and translation config. In which version are you seeing that ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to translations inside your code and not inside the templates you will have to write a custom function:

```
private function translate($translationKey, array $parameters = array(), $translationDomain = 'messages') 
{

    $tranlation = $this->get('translator.default')->trans($translationKey, $parameters, $translationDomain);
    if ($tranlation != $translationKey) {
        return $tranlation;
    }
    else {
        throw new \Exception();
    }
}
```

Hint: You can/should create a custom exception for this case

**Update:**

What you want will only be possible if you create your own translator... this translator class should return `null` if the translation could not be found: 
https://github.com/Orbitale/TranslationBundle/blob/master/Translation/Translator.php

**Additional Info** (referring to the comment):
The info field for missing translations in the symfony developer toolbar seems to be quite new, introduced in a late 2.6 or an early 2.7 release... 
anyway it would look like this:
[image]

***But:*** I just noticed that you can see missing translation-warnings also in earlier versions, you will find them in the toolbar profiler in `Logs` section

Comment: That's the solution i'm currently using, but it will throw an error if the translated string equals the translation id. In my case it doesn't happen, but that's not a perfect solution. +1 Anyway.